# WSO2 ESB with Load balancer and without clustering

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, wso2-esb

I am trying to setup  WSO2 ESB on 2 nodes both sharing the same DB.
and also load balancer handling the loads across these 2 nodes.

Wondering if we really need to do clustering based on WKA scheme across these 2 nodes?

Comment: if clustering is required please let me know the benefits of the same .

Comment: when you say "sharing the same DB", you mean a database used in your mediations (dblookup, ...) or gov & conf registry + user management ?

Comment: Mysql used for user mgmt and conf/gov db , to be shared between the nodes . Not the Mediators .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ESB, synapse configurations are not stored in the DB, they are stored in the File System, So Yes HazleCast based clustering is required since the artifacts are synced between the nodes using a SVN based deployment synchronizer. When the manager node gets a new artifact (Say API, Proxy etc.) it will broadcast a syncing message to all the Worker nodes in the cluster, then worker nodes will checkout any new artifacts from the SVN. You can read more about this from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer+for+Carbon+4.2.0-Based+Products)

Comment: so i see the only downside with my approach is deployment needs to be done on both of my nodes ? If I manage to do that either manually or by 2 jenkins jobs one for each node am I Good to go ? or you see any other issues .

Comment: :) not really, There are few more places clustering is used. If you are using any coordination related operations. E.g : Message Processors, Schedules Tasks etc. HZ is used to coordinate these in the cluster. If you are not using any of these you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the info , our usecases are  req-resp , stateless api's, i hope we are good to go in this case.

Comment: Yes in that case you don't need clustering.

Comment: Thanks for the info.